# After installing Ubuntu Windows is unable to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

Windows was pre-installed on this machine before installing Ubuntu as a secondary OS.
They are both installed on 1 drive

When choosing Windows 10 from the GRUB menu this shows up on the console:

```
Setting partition type to 0x7
error: can't find command `drivemap'.
error: invaild EFI file path.

Press any key to continue...
```

After pressing Enter it kicks me back into the GRUB menu

This is what Windows is called on it:
Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)

Edit: after updating grub the boot menu for it doesnt appear anymore

Comment: Grub can only boot working Windows. Please try booting Windows directly (UEFI settings > Boot) and if it boots correctly make sure to install all pending updates while rebooting as many times it needs. Then disable Fast Startup, a must when dual-booting, and shutdown. Change the boot order back to Ubuntu and then run `sudo update-grub`. Any change? Please [edit] your question to update it accordingly.

Comment: I always never was able to update windows even though it asked to. Fast startup was also disabled. The only difference it did was that the GRUB menu didn't show up.

Comment: This website is about Ubuntu, not Winbdows. If you have problems with Windows you may want to ask at superuser.com. And yes, you should fix your Windows before anything else.